# How to make new line in JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to make the text as a list but it is still in one line.

Here is my code:

```
model.addElement(new Product("Bags", "Prada Gucci  Herschel  Hawk  CLN"));
model.addElement(new Product("Watches", "Timex \n Tissot \n Swatch \n Casio \n Seiko"));
model.addElement(new Product("Shoes", "Under Armour \n Nike \n Vans \n Adidas \n Timberland"));
model.addElement(new Product("Jewelry", "Cartier \n Pandora \n Mikimoto \n Bulgari \n Foundrae"));
model.addElement(new Product("Car", "Toyota \n Mitsubishi \n Tesla \n Suzuki \n Honda"));

list.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(e -> {
    Product p = list.getSelectedValue();
    label.setText("Items: " + p.getItem());
});
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Don’t you want Timex, Tissot, etc., to be individual *items* in the list?

Comment: This seems better suited to using a `JTree`. "Bags", "Watches" etc would be the top-level branches, while things like ""Timex", "Tissot" etc would be leaves on those branches.

Comment: What @AndrewThompson said is correct. For a nasty kludge, try `model.addElement(new Product("Car", "<html>Toyota<br>Mitsubishi<br>Tesla<br>Suzuki<br>Honda</html>"));

`

Comment: C'mon @g00se! You could at least have used nested(?) **HTML lists** (`<ol>` & `<ul>`). If you're gonna kludge, may as well do it in style. ;)

Comment: Haha yes. You could even write a simple method that returns a hacked html string like `Product.itemsToHtml()`. I think part of the problem with the original q. is that it looks like the second argument to the ctor of `Product` is `String` when it should at least be `String[]`

Comment: A JLabel doesn't support the newline string. Display the data in a JTextArea which will support the newlines. You can always make the text area non-editable.